# Why When I Click A href with base url the Page is 404 Not Found using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello Everyone I want To Ask Why When Change Page using href i got 404 Not Found?

this is the path on my codeigniter

this config my base url

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Fenix/';`

this is config for index page

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

and i already give .httacess on root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And href i want to click

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="<?php echo base_url('controllers/Login_Controller')?>">Login</a></li>
```

And The Controller

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
     public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

Can Anyone Help Me About This I'm Still New About Codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should use this

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="<?php echo site_url('Login_Controller')?>">Login</a></li>
```

in codeigniter you have not to call a folder just controller and the function and when you call Login_Controller codeigniter will automatically read function **index()**

hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

before =>

```
href="<?php echo base_url('controllers/Login_Controller')?>"
```

after =>

```
href="<?=site_url('login_Controller')?>"
```

You can to use `$this-load->helper('url')`, if necessary

You can see the full document [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)